# filtering a list of entries in python

Tags: python, list, filter

I need to filter a list of character ie

```
    In [16]: list
    Out[16]: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [2, 3, 6, 3, 6, 2, 7], [4, 5, 9, 3, 1, 8]]
```

characters to grep is, `g = [4,8]`

```
    In [27]: a = filter(lambda x:g in x, list)

    In [28]: a
    Out[28]: []
```

But I am ending up with this. Can someone help me?

I need the output as

```
   [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [4, 5, 9, 3, 1, 8]]
```

Comment: As a list comprehension: `a = [i for i in l if any(j in i for j in (4,8))]`

Comment: in that case change `any` to `all`: `a = [i for i in l if all(j in i for j in (4,8))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `g in x` is never `True` because `g` is a list that and that is never within one of your sub-lists, e.g. (`[4,8] in [4,8,7]` returns `False`). The right approach with `filter`:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [2, 3, 6, 3, 6, 2, 7], [4, 5, 9, 3, 1, 8]]
g = [4,8]
filter(lambda x:all(c in x for c in g), l)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [4, 5, 9, 3, 1, 8]]
```

Or list comprehension:

```
[item for item in l if all(c in item for c in g)]
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [4, 5, 9, 3, 1, 8]]
```

Note, don't name your variables `list`, this shadows the built-in  name

Comment: I need both the entries in g should be present. ie, if my list is `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [2, 3, 6, 3, 6, 2, 8], [4, 5, 9, 3, 1, 8]]`, output should be `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [4, 5, 9, 3, 1, 8]]` for `g=[4,8]`

Comment: @VinodiniNatrajan Updated my answer to fit this requirement, I just needed to change `any()` to `all()`